# Creating primary key on two columns

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite GUI Browser to work with the database. I can't find any button to make primary key on two or more columns. How to do this?

Comment: Which GUI Browser would that be?

Comment: The one that is available from SQLite website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite [does not support](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) adding a constraint.

You have to create a new table, specifying its whole column structure, and import old data into the new table. Then remame the new one, after having dropped the old one.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question. Suppose columns are: SID and TranID. I want a composite key on SID, TranID. How to do this?

Comment: Then use the SQLite shell. It is not complicated :) `create table foo(a text, b text, primary key(a,b));`